# Perfect-forwarding callable objects in higher-order functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I had been writing higher-order functions like this:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void doStuff(F f, Args&&... args)
{
    // ...
    f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // ...
}
```

Or maybe replace `F f` with `F&& f`.

But after I learned about ref-qualifiers (ouch), things got complicated. Imagine a functor class:

```
struct Foo {
    void operator()(...) &;
    void operator()(...) &&;
};
```

Then my previous implementations of `doStuff` will only ever call the `&` method, since parameters are always lvalues.

I think the way to resolve this is to implement `doStuff` like this:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
void doStuff(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    // ...
    std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    // ...
}
```

This is also how `std::result_of` is [possibly implemented](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of#Possible_implementation). What I want to know is, is there any drawback to this implementation, i.e., should I replace all my HOF implementations with it?

Comment: It looks good as long as `f` is not going to be reused after that. It's possible that `operator()` will have some side-effects that may modify internal members (move on internal members) of `f` (if any). I am not sure though, haven't thought it through..Good question.

Comment: @Arunmu If (1) the method is overloaded on ref-qualifiers, and (2) the caller passes the functor in as an rvalue, we have enough reason to believe that the caller intends to call the `&&` version. That being the case, it's probably reasonable to perfect-forward every occurrence of `f` in `doStuff`...I think.

Comment: I don't see any problem with `forward<F>(f)` as long as don't use `f` again within `doStuff`

Comment: @Praetorian Why would using `f` again be a problem? `std::forward` is nothing more than a conditional cast, so unless the `&&` method blows up the object itself, reusing `f` should be fine. No?

Comment: Well, yes, but if I go through the trouble of implementing ref qualified overloads, I'd probably only do it when the `&&` overload has a chance to be more efficient by stealing the guts of the functor. In any case, unless you also control every single functor that will be passed to `doStuff`, you have to assume that it has an `operator()() &&` that modifies the functor so that subsequent calls may behave differently.

Comment: @Praetorian Good point.

Comment: @ZizhengTai My point expressed clearly by Praetorian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::forward` is a conditional r-value cast, and the point is as usual to steal the guts out of dying objects. There's no difference between `functors` and other objects in this respect. The down-side is same as with any use of `std::forward`; if you are not prepared to steal those guts, you shouldn't.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int>& operator()(...) & {
        return vec;
    }
    std::vector<int> operator()(...) && {
        return std::move(vec);
        // Clearly, don't rely on 'vec' here...
    }
};

Foo getFoo(){
    return {};
}

int main() {
    auto foo = getFoo();
    auto vec1=foo();
    auto vec2=getFoo()();
}
```

Clearly, don't do things like this:

```
auto vec3 = std::move(foo)();
vec4 = foo();
```

for the same reasons.